# Oracle sql regular expression to split a string by a pattern

Tags: sql, oracle

```
| email                           |
+---------------------------------+
| abcd@gmail.com                  |
| bdef@gmail.com abdfgr@yahoo.com |
+---------------------------------+
```

I tried the below and it is working for the 1st row

```
substr(email,instr(email,'@',1,1))
```

But for 2nd row on a same cell we have 2 domain id. Now, how to retrieve the output as below

```
gmail.com
gmail.com
yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
SQL> with test (email) as
  2    (select 'abcd@gmail.com' from dual union
  3     select 'bdef@gmail.com abdfgr@yahoo.com' from dual
  4    )
  5  select ltrim(regexp_substr(email, '@(\w+\.\w+)', 1, column_value), '@') res
  6  from test,
  7       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                           connect by level <= regexp_count(email, '@' )
  9                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

RES
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

gmail.com
gmail.com
yahoo.com

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR, for Example:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('jlora@outlook.com', '(\@).*') from DUAL
```

**Result: @outlook.com**

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following. I'm assuming you have a primary key column or columns on the table that also has the email column:

```
 SELECT id, TRIM('@' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, '@\S+', 1, LEVEL))
   FROM mytable
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, '@\S+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    -- If you have a composite key, mention all of the columns here:
    AND PRIOR id = id
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL;
```

[**See SQL Fiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e595/2) (ignore the schema!).

Now the above query will get all results, including duplicates, so if a value in the `email` column looks like this: `you@yahoo.com you@gmail.com you@gmail.com` then `gmail.com` will be returned twice for that primary key value. Simply replace the `SELECT` with `SELECT DISTINCT` to get around that issue (if you want to get around it).